# Loop postgres query on python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

My data looks like this:

```
ID   Raw_status    Final_status    filter    weight
1    2             3               filter1   400
2    3             1               filter1   100
3    3             2               filter2   200
4    1             1               filter2   300
5    2             2               filter3   210
6    3             1               filter3   90
7    1             1               N/A       50
8    2             2               N/A       110
```

What I want is to study the impact of each filter on the raw_status.
I made this query :

```
select case when filter=filter1 then 
        (case when Raw_status<>Final_status then Raw_status
        else Raw_status end)
    else Raw_status
    End as impact,
    count(*),
    sum(weight)
    from table1
    group by impact
```

I got the result that I want for filter1, which looks like:

```
impact   count   weight
1        3       450
2        2       320
3        3       690
```

I want to do this in python in a more functional way instead of changing the filter in the query each time. Can anyone help? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please explain the logic for `impact`.

Comment: will consider only the final_status of that filter and count them with other raw_status , meaning if filter 1 change the status of id 1 and 2 from (2,3) into (3,1) i will count the (3,1) with the rest of raw status

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by *change the filter each time*? Do a simple loop in python and execute the query at each pass. For performance gain you can use `prepare` call before loop and do variable binding at loop. Also please tag your DBMS

Comment: `case when <something> then raw_status else raw_status end` looks like a typo

Comment: @astentx to see the impact of each filter i should change the name every time, and about the loop can you give an example? thank you

Comment: What the python code do you have so far? It's always better to try something first by yourself to learn something, so it will not be useful if I write the code for you from scratch.